# Get index of the same value from two arraylist with two different sizes/length

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to Java and I want to get the index of same value of two arraylist however the two arraylist do NOT have the same size/length. This is the working code:

```
List<String> new_valueString = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> new_fieldsString = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> oldValueString = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> oldFieldsString = new ArrayList<>();

  if (new_fieldsString.size() != 0 && new_valueString.size() != 0) {
        for (int l = 0; l < new_fieldsString.size(); l++) {
                if (new_fieldsString.get(l).equalsIgnoreCase(oldFieldsString.get(l))) {
                    field_index = l;
                    if (!new_valueString.get(field_index).contains(oldValueString.get(field_index))) {
                        ifUpdated = true;
                    } else {
                        ifUpdated = false;
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

I want to get the index of the same value between new_fieldsString and oldFieldsString and use that index to compare the new_valueString and oldValueString.

Comment: Could you describe your case in moire details? Because in your code you are not looking for index of same value in 2 arrays, you are comparing values for same index instead. Could you give example of new and old values arrays and expected results?

Comment: What error you are facing now?

Comment: is `indexOf` not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello You need a two for sentences one for your first array and second to compare with the short arraylist and when you find your condition true not forget break the loop, some like this:

```
List<String> new_valueString = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> new_fieldsString = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> oldValueString = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> oldFieldsString = new ArrayList<>();

  if (new_fieldsString.size() != 0 && new_valueString.size() != 0) {
        for (int l = 0; l < new_fieldsString.size(); l++) {
           for (int m = 0; m < oldFieldsString.size(); m++) {
                if (new_fieldsString.get(l).equalsIgnoreCase(oldFieldsString.get(m))) {
                    if (!new_valueString.get(l).contains(oldValueString.get(m))) {
                        ifUpdated = true;
                    } else {
                        ifUpdated = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```